# SQL script for string replacement with excel mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

My DB has a column "Codes" which contains several thousands of "old strings"

| Codes |
| --- |
| Old String 1 |
| Old String 2 |
| Old String 3 |
| Old String.. |

I have an excel file that contains a mapping of these "old strings" with their corresponding "new strings"

| Old Codes | New Code |
| --- | --- |
| Old String 1 | New String 1 |
| Old String 2 | New String 2 |
| Old String 3 | New String 3 |
| Old String.. | New String.. |

My excel file may contains some string pairs which don't have a corresponding "old string" in the DB.

I want to make some kind of SQL script which can find and replace all the Old strings in the Codes column of my DB with the corresponding new strings as mapped in my excel sheet.

Comment: What's wrong with the `REPLACE` function?

Comment: If you could dump the Excel file into a SQL table, then it would be a simple `UPDATE TableWithCodes SET Code = NewCode FROM TableWithCodes INNER JOIN MappingFromExcel ON OldCode = Code`

Comment: @Larnu unfortunately I don't know how to do that

Comment: @RuudHelderman I can't dump the excel into an SQL table. Architect doesn't want that...

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? It's not the hardest function to understand.

Comment: @AmateurKyrill "Architect doesn't want that." I can relate to that, but it indicates your question is lacking on constraints. Please edit, add details. Are you allowed to use temporary tables? Are you allowed to use linked servers? Are you allowed to use OPENROWSET? Must everything be automated, or is it acceptable to have some manual steps?